# Is it possible to use MassTransit Transactional Outbox in a Multi-Tenant per DB architecture?

Tags: multi-tenant, masstransit

The main objective is to guarantee the reliability of the message delivery of our integration events in case of failures with the Application or DB, and in this scenario the new Transactional Outbox seems to be the most indicated.

With the MT Transactional Outbox, the writing (publishing) of our integration events happens atomically in the Commit of our Command Handlers.

Our solution is built as microservices that use one DB per tenant. However, the applications are shared and the DB (connection string) selection is built into the request scope.

The Outbox MT tables (OutboxMessage, In/OutboxState) are created in each tenant DB and with that we have the atomic writing of the operation along the triggering of integration events.

The problem is in the delivery to the Bus. How to make the MT background services (DeliveryService and InboxCleanupService) reach the outbox in the tenant DB, since there is no request to identify the tenant in advance?

It wouldn't be a problem if the application also runs in an environment for each tenant with their respective configuration / connection string, but that's not the case.

An alternative would be to create a third application dedicated only to running delivery/cleanup services for all tenants in separate tasks.

But to use MT delivery, we would have to dynamically create a DbContext instance (with only the Mappings for MT) for each tenant at startup. I don't know if this is the best way and it also doesn't seem possible to use the MassTransit configuration API this way.

Does anyone have an advice, approach or guide that could help us?

Answer (score 4):

We were having exactly the same issue as you are describing, and we've ended up with the solution you are essentially describing yourself, a separate service that does nothing but outbox delivery and inbox cleanup.
For every MassTransit endpoint, we disable both outbox delivery and inbox cleanup

```
mt.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<ContextWithOutboxTables>(outbox =>
{
    var outboxConfig = outbox.UseSqlServer();
    outboxConfig.DisableInboxCleanupService();
    outboxConfig.UseBusOutbox(busOutbox =>
    {
            busOutbox.DisableDeliveryService();
    });
}
```

and the separate service is configured similar to the below (with some code replaced/removed)

```
builder.ConfigureServices(s =>
{
    foreach (var connectionString in distinctTenantConnectionStrings)
    {
        IServiceCollection outboxServices = new ServiceCollection();
        outboxServices.AddDbContext<ContextWithOutboxTables>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });
        var outboxContainer = outboxServices.BuildServiceProvider();
        
        s.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(container =>
        {
            return new BusOutboxDeliveryService<ContextWithOutboxTables>(
                container.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>(),
                new OptionsWrapper<OutboxDeliveryServiceOptions>(new OutboxDeliveryServiceOptions()
                {
                    // tweak your options here
                }),
                new OptionsWrapper<EntityFrameworkOutboxOptions>(new EntityFrameworkOutboxOptions()
                {
                    LockStatementProvider = new SqlServerLockStatementProvider(),
                    // tweak your options here
                }),
                logger,
                outboxContainer);
        });
        
        s.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(container =>
            new InboxCleanupService<ContextWithOutboxTables>(new OptionsWrapper<InboxCleanupServiceOptions>(
                new InboxCleanupServiceOptions()
                {
                    // tweak your options here
                }),
            logger,
            outboxContainer)
        );
    }
});
```

It is necessary to register the hosted service using the `AddSingleton<IHostedService>` override instead of `AddHostedService` because MS dependency injection eliminates duplicate service implementations under the covers, which is not the behavior you want, you ARE actually registering the same hosted service multiple times, with different configuration.

Creating a separate container via

```
IServiceCollection outboxServices = new ServiceCollection();
```

is necessary due to MT resolving the data context from the container, and you need it to provide a differently configured data context (connection string) for each instance of the hosted service.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your implementation and sorry for the late response.

In the end, we used MT's Courier feature (Routing Slip) which was the best fit for our needs.

Courier brought other benefits, such as the ease of implementing compensation routines and also dispensed with the use of our Tenant DB for message persistence, as in this model the broker itself guarantees this persistence.